# Help with a sentence translation with many prepositions

Tags: translation, preposition, meaning-in-context

I was doing the reading part of a B2 sample test and I stumbled across this sentence:

> Museen gelten nach wie vor und trotz aller gegenteiligen Bemühungen gerade unter Jugendlichen als verstaubt und uncool.

What strikes me is that this sentence has three consecutive prepositions, making a translation really hard to perform for me. Here is my translation:

> Despite contrary efforts, Museums are regarded as old-fashioned and uncool among young people.

**Nach wie vor** doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

*Nach wie vor* is a fixed expression. Its meaning is simply: *still*.
Common synonyms are *immer noch* and *weiterhin*.

See [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nach_wie_vor), [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nach_wie_vor).

Translation are provided by any bilingual dictionary, e.g. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=nach%20wie%20vor) or [Pons](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=nach%20wie%20vor&l=deen&in=&lf=de).

You can grasp its meaning this way:
*Nach* refers to a time after something. *Vor* refers to a time before something. *Wie* is used for comparison. *Nach wie vor* means literally *afterwards like before*.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably the most accurate one:

> In spite of all contrary efforts museums are still considered as outdated and uncool, especially among young people.

trotz: in spite of
nach wie vor: still
gerade: especially
aller: of all

Comment: I think the passage refers to a change from the past.